# Space usage not correct

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

When I run

```
df -H
```

I can see that the root / is using 100% of the space:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      423G  423G     0 100% /
udev            2.0G  8.2k  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           787M  209k  787M   1% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       423G  209M  402G   1% /mnt
```

So I wanted to understand what directories are using more space, and with:

```
du -sh /
```

The result is telling me that the root is only using 62G

```
62G /
```

How is this possible? Where is the rest of the space used?